# How to create unique id for each form submission in contact form 7?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I need to provide a unique id for all participants of the event who is registering for the events online. I wanted to give a unique id something like "17CONF001, 17CONF002, ..."

### How to achieve this?

I am using the contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension plugin for a registration process in my website for this purpose.

### Work done:

I am using the following function to generate ticket number.

```
/* Generate Quote Ticket */
function genTicketString() {
$length = 3;
$iclaa = "17ICLAA";
$characters = "0123456789";
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
}
return $iclaa.$string;
}
add_shortcode('quoteticket', 'genTicketString');
```

in  my functions.php and I have added

```
[dynamictext ticket "quoteticket"]
```

in my form in contact form 7 and made this field invisible through css.

Lastly, I have added [ticket] to your my e-mail body.

As per the solution given by [AMCD](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-generating-reference-number).

### Problems with this code:

Each refresh gives different reference number whereas it should generate the reference number for each submission of forms.

Comment: Why not generate the ticket number in the script that receives the form data when submitted rather than the script that outputs the form?

Comment: if so, kindly provide an answer. I am a newbie to this... Any help would be pleasurable.. @infinigrove

Comment: I'm not that familiar with wordpress or contact-form-7 to give you a detailed answer yet.  Could your post the code that receives the form data and generates the e-mail?  That would be where you need to make changes.

Comment: @infinigrove yes...it gets the data from the form and generates email.

Comment: Basically you need to call your `genTicketString()` function when you receive the data rather than when you generate the form.  I can't really give you a more detailed answer unless you update your question to also include the code that gets the data from the form and generates the email.

Answer (score 3):

hope this can help, add this code to your function.php

```
//Define the key to store in the database
define( 'CF7_COUNTER', 'cf7-counter' );

//Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
function cf7dtx_counter(){
    $kodeawal = "FJY";
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;  //Increment the current count
    return $kodeawal.$val;
}
add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

//Action performed when the mail is actually sent by CF7
function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
    update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');
```

Then, add this to your contact form 7

```
<p>[dynamictext cf7-counter "CF7_counter"]</p>
```

The output on your form will be "FJY1", "FJY2", and so

Thank you to sevenspark:
http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-counter-for-contact-form-7

Comment: Yes, but if you open the same form with different browsers in the same time, each browser will have the same number.

Comment: @emir, any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate random number as an ID just use this.

```
define( 'CF7_COUNTER', 'cf7-counter' );

function cf7dtx_counter(){
    $length = 8;
    $characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;
    update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val);
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');
```

Then, add this to your contact form 7

`[dynamichidden Request-ID "CF7_counter"]`